# Absolute Positioning of Date in Front Page

Tags: positioning

I'm trying to fix the layout of the font page of my Master Thesis.
As you can see in the uploaded image the date is not put at the bottom of the page.

[image]

I've tried to move it down with the `\vspace` or `\vfill` commands, but the result was either no movement, or moving it to next page.

Is there some instruction for putting it at the very bottom of page?And what are the commands for doing it if I tried to set the absolute positioning of the text?

Note that I put the date with sample text and not by using the `\date` command and make title one. This is the code for the front page:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{./images/Logo_Unisi_2012.jpg}
\end{figure}    


\begin{center}
    {\large UNIVERSITY OF SIENA} \medskip \\
    {\large DEPARTMENT OF ENGINEERING} \vspace*{0.5cm} \\
    {\Large Master Thesis in Computer Science Engineering} \vspace*{2.0cm} \\
    \doublespacing
    {\huge \textbf{This is the long title of my Master thesis}} \vspace*{2.3cm}
\end{center}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft}
        {\large \textit{Author}:\vspace*{0.5cm} \\ Me
        }
    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}%
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright}
        {\large \textit{Supervisor}:\vspace*{0.5cm} \\ Him \\
        }
        \vspace*{0.5cm}
        {\large \textit{Advisors}:\vspace*{0.5cm}\\First\vspace*{0.1cm}\\Second\vspace*{0.1cm}\\Third\\
        }
    \end{flushright}    
\end{minipage}%

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
    \vfill
    \begin{center}
        {\large 10 December 2012}
    \end{center}    
    \begin{center}
        {\large Academic Year 2011/2012}
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}%
\end{center}    

\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: tried to insert the `\vspace{0.3cm}` inside to `\begin{minipage}`

Comment: @karathan - nothing changed...nor by using `\vspace` or `\vspace*` or `\vfill`

Comment: It is best to put a complete file that with copy-paste can directly test it

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: You should give an example containing at minimum that needs to be run like `\documentclass{...}` and `\usepackage{...}`

Comment: With TikZ you can do absolute positioning: `\documentclass[12pt]{article} \usepackage{tikz} \begin{document} \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw (current page.south) + (0,2) node {10 December, 2012}; \end{document}` (requires two compilations).

Comment: @Matteo: Please provide a link to where you were told to not provide a complete document? Yes, you should _minimize_ the code to only what is needed to reproduce the problem. Start with what you have and eliminate things that are definitely not related.  For example in you code above if you take out the entire `center` environment where you specify `UNIVERSITY OF SIENA`, does the problem still occur. If so, take it out as that is not needed to reproduce the problem. But the  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) should start with `\documentclass` and end with `end{document}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill - just updated code. I think you can compile it straight away.Let me know...

Comment: @PeterGrill - this is link for logo if you need it (http://www.google.it/imgres?hl=en&sa=X&tbo=d&biw=1680&bih=914&tbm=isch&tbnid=jx6aaEfagXnS1M:&imgrefurl=http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Logo_Unisi_2012.jpg&docid=ZJmb1F6jt0MXrM&imgurl=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/c/c8/Logo_Unisi_2012.jpg&w=300&h=300&ei=7EC3UNLyMYjdtAa_8YDICw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=1072&vpy=150&dur=2&hovh=225&hovw=225&tx=100&ty=117&sig=105706707002010527184&page=1&tbnh=166&tbnw=183&start=0&ndsp=51&ved=1t:429,r:7,s:0,i:106)

Comment: One way would be to use `geometry` package to adjust the margin of title page. Use `\newgeometry{bottom=1cm}` to change bottom margin to 1cm, add `\vfill` to move the date to bottom and then `\restoregeometry` to revert back to normal margins. Another option would be to set the date in footer and have a separate footer style for title page.

Comment: @mythealias - i have compiling error saying: `! Undefined control sequence \newgeometry`, are these the correct names of commands and package?thks for help

Comment: @Matteo they work for me. check if your packages are up to date.

Comment: which font do you use? Some usepackage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to move the bottom lines:

- Removing `\begin{center}...\end{center}` around the `minipage` to avoid the additional space added by environment `center`. Change the width of the `minipage` to full text width.
- `\vspace{\fill}` fills the available space without guessing the amount.
- Using `\enlargethispage` to get a larger height of the text body.
- `\vspace` at the end of the `minipage` with negative value.

Example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\enlargethispage{\footskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{center}
    \onehalfspacing
    \large
    UNIVERSITY OF SIENA\\
    DEPARTMENT OF ENGINEERING

    \vspace{5mm}

    \Large
    Master Thesis in Computer Science Engineering

    \vspace{20mm}

    \huge
    \textbf{This is the long title of my Master thesis}
\end{center}

\vspace{23mm}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \raggedright
    \onehalfspacing
    \large
    \textit{Author}:\\[.5\baselineskip]
    Me
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \raggedleft
    \onehalfspacing
    \large
    \textit{Supervisor}:\\[.5\baselineskip]
    Him

    \vspace{5mm}

    \textit{Advisors}:\\[.5\baselineskip]
    First\\
    Second\\
    Third
\end{minipage}%

\vspace{\fill}

\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \onehalfspacing
    \large   
    10 December 2012\\
    Academic Year 2011/2012

    \vspace{-20mm} 
\end{minipage}%

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]